# Windows Mobile - Accessing Application's table from PC

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync

I'd like to know how to access the data stored in the SQL server tables from Windows Mobile to PC.

for e.g. I can add many data to the application and when I connect to the PC, I'd like to access it.

We can use SQL Server Sync for synchronizing the data and using web services, it's possible to access the data but this has dependency with IIS.

Is there any better methods to access the data from application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to the PC you get an ActiveSync/Window Device Center connection.  With that you get tow things:

- Avaiability of Remote API (RAPI) methods
- A NDIS network connection

Neither of these provide an "out-of-the-box" mechanism for communicating with the database, so you have to either develop or acquire something that will do it for you.  Here you would have just about any number of options, but a few that come to mind are:

- Use a third-party solution like [Primeworks DesktopSqlCe](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DesktopSqlCe.html)
- Create [your own RAPI extension DLL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299891) that allows you to pass down commands and get back results
- Create a proprietary client/server application and protocol that uses sockets to allow you to send commands and get results
- Use [Microsoft's Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx) to synchronize the data
- Use [SQL Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172367.aspx)